# In Firefox, how can I achieve a prompt for save-as file name?

Tags: firefox

Built in PDF viewer in Firefox is great. About 5% of PDF files viewed, a user may want to keep; however under a file name that is chosen/defined by him.

When in the viewer and clicking save - how can I achieve FF to prompt me for save-as name? (or any work-around achieving this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in viewer only has a download function and does not prompt to set the filename. However, it is still possible to do it via the `Firefox` menu. To specify the file name, use `File` → `Save Page As...` menu option.

Comment: It does prompt for the file name when you ask it to save. What version of Firefox are you using?

Answer (score 4):

In the preferences dialog, General tab, under Downloads, select Always ask....

[image: Screenshot of preferences | general tab]

Edit: If this is too general, there is a similar option for each file type in the Applications tab:

[image: screenshot of preferences | applications tab]

Comment: The OP want to do it for PDF, but not for ZIP files or .EXE or .MSI files. So it is good, but not good enough to activate this option.

Answer (score 1):

The web application that delivers the PDF file to your browser can set HTTP headers for content-type and content-disposition.  That's how the browser knows to treat it as a PDF file and pull up the viewer.  It's also how the web application can send your browser a default filename that comes up when you do a Save As.  That works better for attachment content-dispositions than for inline ones.

Comment: This explains how the file name is specified by the server, but not how to override it.

Comment: True, the user has to pull up a Save As browser dialog. This just explains where the default filename in the dialog comes from. (For inline dispositions it defaults to the page name instead.)